# Query by date(oracle date in db and local date in java entity) is not working in spring java

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa-2.0, localdate

I am trying to query by date in spring repository class but its not working.Its working fine with local h2-database but its not working with Oracle database.

In controller class:-

```
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<OrderLine>> getOrderDetails(@RequestParam("headerSummaryId") Long headerSummaryId,
        @RequestParam(value = "eventMonth",
                required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate eventMonth) {

    List<OrderLine> od = orderLineService.getOrderDetails(headerSummaryId, Optional.ofNullable(eventMonth));
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(od);
 }
```

In service class:-

```
@Override
public List<OrderLine> getOrderDetails(Long headerSummaryId, Optional<LocalDate> eventMonth) {

    List<OrderLine> olList = new ArrayList<>();
        olList = orderLineSummaryRepo.findByHeaderSummaryIdAndEventMonthAndVisibleFlag(headerSummaryId,
                eventMonth.get(), true);
                return olList;
 }
```

In repository class:-

```
List<OrderLine> findByHeaderSummaryIdAndEventMonthAndVisibleFlag(Long headerSummaryId, LocalDate eventMonth,
        Boolean visibleFlag);
```

The date type for event month in entity class is LocalDate.
I have used org.eclipse.persistence.jpa version 2.6.4.

Comment: How is it not working ? Is the query failing, or returning unexpected results ?

Comment: Query is not failing.It is not able to retrieve any data(correct parameters are provided).Query is returning null.

Comment: The where clause of query is 
WHERE (((HEADER_SUMMARY_ID = ?) AND (EVENT_MONTH = ?)) AND (IS_VISIBLE_FLAG = ?))
@PaulNUK

Answer (score 0):

Register `Jsr310JpaConverters.class` by adding it as a base package class to your EntityScan annotation

e.g.

```
@EntityScan(
        basePackageClasses = {YourAppplication.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class}
)
```

Comment: I am using @EntityScan({".......", "org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten"})
this already in entity scan.